# How do I replace a D Flip Flop with a JK Flip Flop

Tags: automata

[image]

Hello I have this circuit with this I want to learn about Mealey and Moore.

Is this a Mealy Automata? I would say yes because of the upper LED depends on the variables I got.

Otherwise isn't the line of J the next State? So it is a Moore because it only depends on its states?

Now I want to replace the D Flip Flop with a JK how could I do this?

I would just implement a JK to change it but I guess there are things that have to be done so the automata has the same outputs.
Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just as a hint, the general way to solve a problem like this is to write a truth table. The "inputs" to the truth table are the inputs to the machine plus the states of the flip-flops (one bit per FF), and the "outputs" are the outputs of the machine and the outputs of the flip-flops.

From that truth table, you can see if it's a Mealy machine. And given the desired "state on this time" and "state next time", and you can work out what the inputs to a J-K flip-flop should be:

```
 Q Q' | J K
------+-----
 0 0  | 0 X
 0 1  | 1 X
 1 0  | X 1
 1 1  | X 0
```

Where X is "don't care".

I only mentioned the truth table because you wanted to show that it was a Mealy machine, and finding the mapping of inputs and outputs is a definite way to get there.

As for the main question you're asking, you can't replace a D flip flop with a JK flip flop in the general case due to timing. D flip flops "read" their input on (say) the leading edge of the clock, and "output" their result effectively straight away, after a short propagation delay. JK flip flops, on the other hand, "read" on the leading clock edge and "output" on the trailing edge.

This property of JK flip flops can be useful; they are extremely resistant to combinational hazards, for example. But it does mean that they respond half a clock cycle later than a D flip flop.

Assuming that this isn't an issue (and I doubt it is in your circuit), you can just feed D into J and not-D into K.

Comment: So what's excactly the process to transform the behaviour of one FF to another type of FF?  I have to write the truth table of the replacement in reverse?

Comment: Hang on, I'll edit the answer.